# Электронное письмо в виде файла

Tags: кодировка, email, base64

На почту переслали письмо, как я понял, в виде файла. По заголовкам кодирование base64 используется. После преобразования получился пдф документ. Вопрос в том, что этого достаточно, для чтения всего документа или какая-то информация потерялась? Так как размер файла из 12+мб стал 5мб?

Comment: imho потерялась. Все же BASE64 кодирует каждые 3 входных байта четырьмя. Поэтому из 12 должно получиться `12 - 12/4 = 9`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, этого достаточно. base64 - не является архивом, этот способ кодирования может увеличивать размер исходных данных.

Answer (score 1):

Размер в base64 был бОльшим по причине того, что в обычной кодировке мы используем символы от 0x00 до 0xFF (т.е. мощность 256), а в base64 - [A-Z,a-z,0-9,\,+] можность алфавита 64